# How do I create an HTML table with labels above the column separator boundary lines

Tags: html, html-table

I'm trying to create an HTML table that displays reservations like:

```
   9am      10am     11am
    |--------|--------|--------|
Mon |<booked>|<booked>|        |
    |--------|--------|--------|
```

I can do most of that easily but I can't figure out how to get the times on the header line to appear centered above the lines between columns as shown above rather than appearing within cells in the columns, e.g.:

```
       9am      10am     11am
    |--------|--------|--------|
Mon |<booked>|<booked>|        |
    |--------|--------|--------|
```

I've been playing around with several workarounds including having 3 columns for every "real" column so I can merge them on the header line but that leaves me needing to fill that middle cell for the data lines to make it look like a simple cell boundary so it's not great.

I feel like it's got to be something simple but google and trial-and-error are failing me so far.

I'm trying to do this within a K2 article on a Joomla web site so I'd prefer a way to do this just in HTML, not defining a CSS stylesheet as that opens a whole other problem with K2 articles in Joomla.

---

EDIT here is what I have thanks to [@Johannes' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68027954/1745001) but avoiding a CSS stylesheet so I don't have to deal with implementing that in K2/Joomla:

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width: 25%; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 25%; vertical-align: middle;"><span style="display: inline-block; transform: translateX(-50%);">9am</span></td>
<td style="width: 25%; vertical-align: middle;"><span style="display: inline-block; transform: translateX(-50%);">10am</span></td>
<td style="width: 25%; vertical-align: middle;"><span style="display: inline-block; transform: translateX(-50%);">11am</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">Mon</td>
<td style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">&lt;booked&gt;</td>
<td style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">&lt;booked&gt;</td>
<td style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please post questions that relate to Joomla and its extensions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange so that 1. you can receive feedback from folks that have an intimate understanding of the CMS and its extensions and 2. So that that community can grow (in content/activity/users).  Our metrics would do better if we didn't have to compete with SO and Forum. https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58842?phase=beta

Comment: @mickmackusa it's not a Joomla question though, it's an HTML question. It came up because I just happen to be using K2 on Joomla but I could be using Foobar on Wordpress or whatever and have the same HTML question.

Comment: Okay, well, it seemed like something that might benefit Joomla users.  And my opinion (generally) regarding why posting is better there is that there may be a Joomla-specific technique that non-Joomla users might not know.  So posting there may yield unforeseen insights. Either way, I hope that you will join JSE and potentially help us to grow the niche community.

Comment: @mickmackusa I just posted a Joomla question to that site (https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/30355/how-can-i-add-tracking-of-user-logout-time-to-user-actions) so we'll see how that goes!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it the following way: Wrap the time indications in `span` tags. Make those spans `inline-block`s, left-align them inside their `th` and move them to the left by half of their own length using `transform: translateX(-50%);`:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px 15px;
}

th {
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: left;
}

th>span {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th><span>9:00</span></th>
    <th><span>10:00</span></th>
    <th><span>11:00</span></th>
    <th><span>12:00</span></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>entry 1</td>
    <td>entry 2</td>
    <td>entry 3</td>
    <td>entry 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>entry 5</td>
    <td>entry 6</td>
    <td>entry 7</td>
    <td>entry 8</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```